# How get using nic id, if have multiple nic

Tags: c++, windows, networking, nic

I have multiple nic. and each nic is setting different ip range (routing table).

if i connect to specific ip, how get nic id actually using nic to connect the ip?

i have short english, sorry ^^;;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working on a project which requires similar functionality. You could try the function GetBestInterface which takes an IP and returns the interface index of the best interface to that IP.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365920%28v=VS.85%29.aspx